# TensorFlow: add_meta_graph() of SavedModelBuilder: Why does every additional meta graph take up the same disk space as the full model?

Tags: tensorflow

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder) of SavedModelBuilder says that the first meta graph added to a SavedModel (via `add_meta_graph_and_variables()`) will be added with variables and that any additional meta graphs (via `add_meta_graph()`) will be added with their graph definition only, i.e. without variables.

However, I tried it out and it doesn't seem to be true. I have a model whose protocol buffer file (`saved_model.pb`) takes up roughly 500 MB with one meta graph. If I add a second meta graph to the SavedModel (which in my case is just a subgraph of the first graph), `saved_model.pb` suddenly takes up roughly 1 GB, i.e. twice as much as before.

If the variables make up the bulk of the file size of the model and are allegedly only saved once, how is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The SavedModel format indeed saves variables shared between meta graphs exactly once.

Is it possible that your model contains large constants (or say the variables are initialized to large constants)? The SavedModel format will be able to re-use the storage for variables but not for constants. For example, consider the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("/tmp/mymodel")

def build_graph():
  # A 10MB numpy value of ones
  init_value = np.ones(10 * (2 ** 20) / 4).astype(np.float32)               
  v = tf.Variable(init_value, name='MyVariable')
  return tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Graph().as_default():          
  with tf.Session() as sess:           
    sess.run(build_graph())            
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ['tag1'])

with tf.Graph().as_default():          
  build_graph()                        
  builder.add_meta_graph(['tag2'])     

builder.save()
```

The saved model here will be ~30MB (`du -csh /tmp/mymodel`):

- 10MB for the variable contents
- 10MB for the constant (initial value) stored in the graph for `tag1`
- 10MB for the constant (inivial value) stored in the graph for `tag2`

If instead, you change the initial value to not be a large constant, e.g., by using something like:

```
init_value = tf.ones([10 * (2 ** 20) / 4])
```

Then you'll observe that the saved model consumes only ~10MB - for the variables as the initialization constants do not need to be stored in the graph.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I'll investigate whether what you suggest might be the reason. The bulk of my model comes from a pre-trained VGG-16 that I load, and I haven't checked out yet whether that contains a lot of large constants. The kernels of the layers I added on top are all initialized with random variables. The biases are initialized with constants, but those alone shouldn't take up that much space.